# While inserting the data this error is populating in error log

Tags: php, mysql, yii

While inserting the data this error is populating in error log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CDbException: CDbCommand failed to execute
>   the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292
>   Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column
>   'date_modified' at row 1 in
>   /var/www/html/yiiframework/db/CDbCommand.php:358

```
            $p = new CHtmlPurifier();

            $params=array(
              'first_name'=>$p->purify($this->data['first_name']),
              'last_name'=>$p->purify($this->data['last_name']),
              'email_address'=>$p->purify($this->data['email_address']),
              'password'=>md5($this->data['password']),
              'date_created'=>FunctionsV3::dateNow(),
              'ip_address'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
              'contact_phone'=>$p->purify($this->data['contact_phone'])
            );

public static function dateNow()
{
    return date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
}
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: And your code??

Comment: Where is your code man? show your code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Add an empty check for empty values and fill them with another value or you can do something like this :

`ALTER TABLE yourTable MODIFY created datetime  NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-02'`

Setting default datetime.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add default value for `date_modified` to null. Or you have to pass this also at created time

```
$params=array(
              'first_name'=>$p->purify($this->data['first_name']),
              'last_name'=>$p->purify($this->data['last_name']),
              'email_address'=>$p->purify($this->data['email_address']),
              'password'=>md5($this->data['password']),
              'date_created'=>FunctionsV3::dateNow(),
              'ip_address'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
              'contact_phone'=>$p->purify($this->data['contact_phone']),
              'date_modified'=>FunctionsV3::dateNow()
            );
```

Comment: i have added the function of datenow()

Comment: You only have to add `'date_modified'=>FunctionsV3::dateNow()` this line. remaining code will be same

Comment: public static function dateNow()
{
    return date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
}

Comment: No change in `dateNow()` function only add `date_modified` in `$params` array

Comment: what value should i pass to that

Comment: I have set that in db as default "0000-00-00 00:00:00" so stil it is showing error..

Comment: See my answer properly I already have mention that `'date_modified'=>FunctionsV3::dateNow()`

Comment: Not set value to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` you can set `NULL` instead. `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is not valid date

Comment: Thanxx it is almost working... but i have made it null by default in database.. bt stil it is not working

Answer (score 1):

As your not setting `date_modified`, unless you have a default value in the database, you need to add something like

```
'date_modified'=>FunctionsV3::dateNow(),
```

to the list of fields your setting.

Comment: i have the default value in database.
it was working fine on my GoDaddy server.. bt when i moved to cloud it's not working